# Firebase database get children long value pass 0 to my class

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I don't know what is my mistake here. I get 0 value for all my long variables.

This is my listener

```
 public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            serviceList.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot dsp : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                serviceList.add(dsp.getValue(Service.class)); //add result into array list

            }

            serviceAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
```

That code run well actually, when I debug, I can see the dsp object has all the values I want. It then passed to my service class object , here it is the structure :

```
    public class Service {

    private String durl;
    private Boolean active;
    private int poin;
    private long priceShort;
    private long priceMedium;
    private long priceLong;
    private long priceLongX;
    private String name;
    private String desc;
    private String category;


    public Service() {  //default constructor

    }

    public Service(String name, String desc,String durl, Boolean active, String category, int poin, long priceShort, long priceMedium, long priceLong, long priceLongX ) {
        this.name = name;
        this.desc = desc;
        this.durl = durl;
        this.active = active;
        this.category = category;
        this.priceShort = priceShort;
        this.priceMedium = priceMedium;
        this.priceLong = priceLong;
        this.priceLongX = priceLongX;
        this.poin = poin;

    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }

    public void setDesc(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public String getDurl() {
        return durl;
    }

    public void setDurl(String durl) {
        this.durl = durl;
    }

    public Boolean getActive() {
        return active;
    }

    public void setActive(Boolean active) {
        this.active = active;
    }

    public int getPoin() {
        return poin;
    }

    public void setPoin(int poin) {
        this.poin = poin;
    }

    public long getPriceShort() {
        return priceShort;
    }

    public void setPriceShort(long priceShort) {
        this.priceShort = priceShort;
    }

    public long getPriceMedium() {
        return priceMedium;
    }

    public void setPriceMedium(long priceMedium) {
        this.priceMedium = priceMedium;
    }

    public long getPriceLong() {
        return priceLong;
    }

    public void setPriceLong(long priceLong) {
        this.priceLong = priceLong;
    }

    public long getPriceLongX() {
        return priceLongX;
    }

    public void setPriceLongX(long priceLongX) {
        this.priceLongX = priceLongX;
    }


}
```

after added to serviceList array, i checked some array objects for the value and everything good except all my long variables like priceShort, priceMedium, priceLong and priceLongX, all has value of 0

What I did :

1. I re-checked the db for the value, its all okay.
2. Restart the app many times.

EDIT/UPDATE: 
Here is my json for service:

```
 "ServicesPrice" : {
    "sid1" : {
      "category" : "Hair-do",
      "desc" : "",
      "name" : "Gunting",
      "poin" : 15,
      "priceLong" : 0,
      "priceLongx" : 0,
      "priceMedium" : 0,
      "priceShort" : 100000
    },
    "sid10" : {
      "category" : "Hair-do",
      "desc" : "",
      "name" : "Coloring Matrix",
      "poin" : 25,
      "priceLong" : 525000,
      "priceLongx" : 625000,
      "priceMedium" : 450000,
      "priceShort" : 375000
    },
    "sid11" : {
      "category" : "Body Treatment",
      "desc" : "Pijat badan 60 menit",
      "name" : "Body Massage",
      "poin" : 15,
      "priceLong" : 0,
      "priceLongx" : 0,
      "priceMedium" : 0,
      "priceShort" : 125000
    },
    "sid12" : {
      "category" : "Body Treatment",
      "desc" : "Massage+Lulur+Sauna+Berendam Rempah+Shampoo Loreal",
      "name" : "Princess Spa",
      "poin" : 25,
      "priceLong" : 0,
      "priceLongx" : 0,
      "priceMedium" : 0,
      "priceShort" : 350000
    },
    "sid13" : {
      "category" : "Body Treatment",
      "desc" : "Lulur Susu + Body Bleaching",
      "name" : "Complete Whitening Milk Spa",
      "poin" : 30,
      "priceLong" : 0,
      "priceLongx" : 0,
      "priceMedium" : 0,
      "priceShort" : 500000
    },
```

Once again, I can get all the values except only all the price

Comment: please post the screenshot of your firebase database structure

Comment: @PhanVanLinh don't ask for a screenshot please. Having the JSON as text is way more reusable. You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thank you. I will remember it in next time

Comment: i added the json snippet i use, please take a look

Comment: Can you add some logging code in your app that shows everything actual is zero?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to post as a comment. Just to confirm, are you using proguard and minifyEnabled in gradle? I tested your code and I got the price back just right.